# Need help on powershell script to retry 5 times if failure

Tags: powershell

I used this Powershell Script to onboard user to create password and enable account. I have no idea why it's randomly get the error An internal error occurred HRESULT: [-2146233087] . When I manually re-try, it's successful. So now I would like to auto re-try 5 times automatically.

Can anyone help on this?

Script

```
function Get-RandomCharacters($length, $characters) {
   $random = 1..$length | ForEach-Object { Get-Random -Maximum 
   $characters.length }
   $private:ofs = ""
   return [String]$characters[$random]
}

function ScrambleString([string]$inputString) {    
   $characterArray = $inputString.ToCharArray()  
   $scrambledStringArray = $characterArray | Get-Random -Count 
   $characterArray.Length    
   $outputString = -join $scrambledStringArray
   return $outputString
}

Start-Sleep -s 30
$GC = "ldap.abc.com:3268"
$DC = "abc.com"

$user = get-aduser -Identity $sam -Properties userPrincipalName, sAMAccountName -Server $GC
$upn = $user.userPrincipalName
$password = $null
$password = Get-RandomCharacters -length 5 -characters 'abcdefghiklmnoprstuvwxyz'
$password += Get-RandomCharacters -length 1 -characters 'ABCDEFGHKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ'
$password += Get-RandomCharacters -length 1 -characters '1234567890'
$password += Get-RandomCharacters -length 1 -characters '!@#$%^*()+='
$password = ScrambleString $password
$sam = $user.sAMAccountName

try {
   Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $sam -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force) -Server $dc
   Set-ADUser -Identity $sam -Server $DC -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
   Enable-ADAccount $user -Server $DC
   $output = @{Password = $Password; AccountName = $UPN } | convertTo-JSON -compress; $output
}

catch {
   Write-Error "Unable to set password, $error"
}
```

I tried to manually re-run the script before, it's workable. What I expect is to auto retry 5 times if failure., so it will reduce my workload.